# How to make jQuery Search functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know plugins exist and already made ones as well, however, I want to make one on my own. I'm stuck though cuz I'm new to jQuery/JavaScript.

Right now no matter how many characters you type in, the entire page disappears instead of showing the words that have the characters I typed. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="searchOption">
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="search"> 
</div>
<div class="searchFound">
    <!--upon hitting enter, this div opens collapse. -->
</div>

    /*Need to get the below search code working...*/
    var thePage = $(".pageContainer");
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var input = $(this).val();
        console.log(input);
        //if match found, make corresponding div link appear in open collapsible div,
        // else say nothing found in open collapsible div
        thePage.each(function(index, value){
            var foundText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            $(value).toggle(foundText.indexOf(input) >= 0);
        });
    });
```

I know toggle will make things 'toggle' for lack of a better word, however, when I use closest or match, thePage does nothing.

I'm looking for some guidance in helping me build this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I attepmted to but couldn't replicate the issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Maybe toss a simple test case up on a site like JSBin or CodePen?

You say the entire page disappears. It sounds like you expect the display of the page to be "filtered" down to elements that match the input. Are you sure the call to `thePage.each()` is behaving the way you want? You may want something like `thePage.children()` in the mix.

http://api.jquery.com/each/

http://api.jquery.com/children/

The specifics are gonna depend on the markup and corresponding DOM tree you're working with. But if you `console.log()` both `index` and `value` within your call to `thePage.each()` I think you'll see surprising results.

Comment: Yes, I want my search results to be filtered in the page. My goal is to make the results appear in a collapsable div under the search bar. The results will have links to the divs where the results really are and those results be highlighted. When I console.log index I see 0 and for value I see the entire ‘page’ div (container div which contains the whole page).  I think this is the right path as I’m getting my page but I’m not finding the results within it. Does that make sense? Would you be able to help me with it? Thanks!!

Comment: Right, so `thePage.each()` is gonna loop over each node in the collection `thePage`, which is just a single node for the entire page. What you wanna do is loop over whatever `div` elements contain the text. So assuming those `div` elements all have a class such as `.word` then you could probably do something like:
`thePage.find('.word').each(...)`
and end up much closer to what you want. If that doesn't work look at the docs for `.children()` and `.contents()`. And it you still haven't gotten it sorted read the docs for all the DOM traversal stuff.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I do want to search the whole page, not just sections of it. Wouldn't thePage.children do it? Yet now using that and your suggestions don't yield any results.

Comment: Without seeing the full thing in context I can really only speculate. But you are dealing with some sort of DOM traversal problem. When you call `$(this).text()` inside your `each()` loop you are looking at the text for the entire page. That's why you get all or nothing behavior. You need to check the text of each "container" one by one. Precisely how you do that is gonna depend on the DOM tree you are working with and that's gonna depend on the markup. Read the docs. Use `console.log()` statements to see what's really going on. And try something new.